# Why define a parameter that is not used, and is there any point?

Tags: ios, swift

Like the following code example, parameters of type PromiseNamespace have no argument names and are not used

```swift
func read<T>(_: PromiseNamespace,
                 file: String = #file,
                 function: String = #function,
                 line: Int = #line,
                 _ block: @escaping (SDSAnyReadTransaction) -> T) -> Promise<T> {
        return Promise { future in
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                future.resolve(self.read(file: file, function: function, line: line, block: block))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hard to see for sure from this but with the generic T I expect it is passed in to the read function so that type T is able to be a confirmed type. I expect something in the PromiseNamespace passed in defines the confirmed type of Promise<T> which is returned from the escaping block. At compile time the generic T needs to be resolved to a confirmed type.

Comment: @Hongtron the code sample from  https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/blob/main/SignalServiceKit/src/Storage/Database/SDSTransactable.swift

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample seems to be from Signal: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/blob/main/SignalServiceKit/src/Storage/Database/SDSTransactable.swift

```
…

public extension SDSTransactable {
    @objc
    func readPromise(file: String = #file,
                     function: String = #function,
                     line: Int = #line,
                     _ block: @escaping (SDSAnyReadTransaction) -> Void) -> AnyPromise {
        return AnyPromise(read(.promise, file: file, function: function, line: line, block) as Promise<Void>)
    }

    func read<T>(_: PromiseNamespace,
                 file: String = #file,
                 function: String = #function,
                 line: Int = #line,
                 _ block: @escaping (SDSAnyReadTransaction) -> T) -> Promise<T> {
        return Promise { future in
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                future.resolve(self.read(file: file, function: function, line: line, block: block))
            }
        }
    }
…
```

I *think* the dummy parameter is used to simply disambiguate between different methods with the same name where other parameters would not be sufficient to do that.

Comment: Maybe you're right. It is still a bit rare to use this method to disambiguate

Comment: I couldn’t find the definition of `PromiseNamespace` using the web (and I didn’t download the code). I suspect it is a simple enum with one case of `promise`. I think the type does nothing other than to allow it to be used for disambiguating.